# Add new bootswatch theme in Jhipster application

Tags: jhipster

I've created a JHipster v6.1.2 application with default theme and now I trying to add a new theme

I did it the following updates and executed `npm install` but without success

added `"bootswatch": "4.3.1"` in **package.json**

added `@import '~bootswatch/dist/yeti/bootswatch'` and `@import '~bootswatch/dist/yeti/variables'` in **vendor.scss**

added `@import '~bootswatch/dist/yeti/variables';` in **global.scss**

updated `"clientTheme": "yeti"` and `"clientThemeVariant": "primary"` in **.yo-rc.json**

Is it missing something?

Comment: Did you get the answer to this?

Comment: @AlGrant yeah bro. Just change the dist import in vendor.scss/global.scss file and rebuild. For example: `@import '~bootswatch/dist/darkly/variables';` to `@import '~bootswatch/dist/materia/variables';` You can check the themes on this [site](https://bootswatch.com/default/)